# How to build C# Code in azure DevOps via visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2008

We want to build C# code via visual studio 2008 in azure devops with self hosted agent.

which task shall we use?

Comment: Its time to upgrade.... 10 years ago :)

Comment: Why do you want to use Visual Studio on a build agent? Why not Visual Studio Build Tools, which are awailable free of charge?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried targeting such an old version of msbuild in a pipeline

However

Visual Studio 2008  = Orcas = `9.0`

[Visual Studio Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops)

`vsVersion` Visual Studio Version

```
- task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '...'
        vsVersion: '9.0'
        configuration: 'release'
        ...
```

<sub>***Note** : complete untested*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> How to build C# Code in azure DevOps via visual studio 2008?

You could use the MSBuild task to build the C# Code in azure DevOps via visual studio 2008.

Just use the specify location of the MSBuild:

[image]

Just specify your local path of the `MSBuild.exe` in this option to build the project/solution.